# Use ampersand in selector name with SASS

Tags: css, sass

Here's what i have in my CSS file ...

```css
.search-doctors-box {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0px;
}

.search-doctors-box--at-map {
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 415px;
    width: 680px;
}
```

I want to achieve this in SASS using the & as the parent selector name and to join it with the rest of the string...

```css
.search-doctors-box {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0px;

    &--at-map {
        position: absolute;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        top: 0px;
        left: 415px;
        width: 680px;
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately there are **limitations to what you can use in combination with the ampersand** in selectors - it expects a class name (`.`), an id (`#`), a pseudo class (`:`), or attribute selectors (`[]`).
Other acceptable symbols that can also be combined with `&` are valid CSS selector combinators , `>`, `+`, and `~`.

---

### **Solution for Sass >= 3.3:**

You can use **string interpolation** on the ampersand `#{&}` and then you can concatenate it with any string.
However, this way (if you do this in a nested rule) a nested selector still automatically gets the parent selectors attached at the beginning:

```
.parent {
  #{&}--at-map { ... }
}
```

would return:

```
.parent .parent--at-map { ... }
```

But, you can save the contents of the ampersand in a variable and use it outside the parent rule. So in your case something along these lines could work:

```
$last-rule: null;
.search-doctors-box {
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
  margin: 0px;
  $last-rule: &;
}
#{$last-rule}--at-map {
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 415px;
  width:680px;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7909803)

or even better, you could use

#### `@at-root`

with nested concatenated selectors, like so:

```
.search-doctors-box {
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
  margin: 0px;

  @at-root #{&}--at-map {
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 415px;
    width:680px;
  }
}
```

which will give you the desired output:

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8088994)

Comment: Your first example doesn't work in the stable version of Sass.  If you're showing off upcoming features, you need to make this clear in your answers.

Comment: +1 for telling me something I didn't know about SCSS.

Comment: @cimmanon thanks ... I'm using the prerelease (v3.3) ... and then I forget that the stable version still lacks some of the features. I made it clear in the answer now.

Comment: @Kitze I added an additional option for Sass >= 3.3 that gives you basically exactly what you want.

Comment: Any idea of when the first option listed in this answer will work? It is a much tidier solution than the others. Thanks for the answer here though, it was very useful!